# Using the value in a cell as a cell reference in a formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to know how to pull cell references from the value of another cell and insert them into a formula.

For a simple example:

In cell A1 I have this: `COUNT(B4:H4)`

Instead of choosing the range when I set up the formula, I'd like this range to be dynamic, based on the value in other cells.

So, I want to type in cell references: in `cell B4`, I'd type in `C5`, and in `H4` I'd type in `C8`. How can I set up my formula to look inside cells `B4` and `H4`, but then return the range that is defined by the values in these cells (`C5:C8` in this case...)
So in the end, cell A1 would return the count of `C5:C8`

I hope that makes sense. It seems like something pretty simple but I can't seem to find info on it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, do you mean you want the sum of `C5:C8` in cell `B4`? I got lost when you said "then return the range that is defined by the values in these cells" You want a cell to return a range?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited to clarify. I want the count of C5:C8 in cell A1. I want my formula to be pointing to cells `B4` and `H4` which will actually contain the text `"C5"` and `"C8"`, respectively.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use `INDIRECT()`

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(<start cell here> & ":" & <end cell here>))
```

Comment: How would you do the same if the formula contained cells from a different sheet and you had to take the sheet from a value in another cell?

Comment: The answer for kkoolpatz is: =SUM(INDIRECT(A2&"!A1")) where A2 contains the sheet name. In gnumeric you need to add the ' (quote), enclosed in double quotes. E.g.: =max(indirect("'"&A2&"'"&"!K:K")) to find the max of column K in the sheet whose name is in cell A2

Answer (score 0):

There is a non-volatile way to do it using INDEX and MAKEARRAY, something like:

```
=COUNT( INDEX(C:C, MAKEARRAY(B4-H4+1, 1, LAMBDA(r,c,B4+r-1))) )
```

Except that now B4 and H4 need only contain the row **numbers** of the start and end i.e. '5' and '8' in your example. This is only simple if you are always talking about single columns you want to process - multiple row-and-column ranges would be possible, but the formula would not be friendly!

Anyway, this is only relevant if you are going to do it a **lot** in your spreadsheet, when INDIRECT would start to slow you down because it **always** recalculates.