# Excel Define a range based on a cell value

Tags: excel, range, cell

Is it possible to define a range based on a value given in a cell.

So, for example:
My selection is A1:A5 That are five cells. is it possible to let excel determine this by setting a cell value (like B1) to 5.

It for the purpose of easily changes a lot of ranges with one change in a cell value. So if I would change the cell value (B1) to 6. The range would automatically change to A1:A6

Even more specific, I would like to do it reversed.

Final example:
Selection should be A6:A10 (this are the five cells). In B1 I have the value 5.
If I change the value of B1 to 6. The range should change to A5:A10

Could somebody help me???

Answer (score 16):

Say you have number 1,2,3,4,5,6, in cell A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6 respectively.
in cell A7 we calculate the sum of A1:Ax. x is specified in cell B1 (in this case, x can be any number from 1 to 6).
in cell A7, you can write the following formular:

`=SUM(A1:INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A",B1)))`

CONCATENATE will give you the index of the cell Ax(if you put 3 in B1, CONCATENATE("A",B1)) gives A3).

INDIRECT convert "A3" to a index.

see this link [Using the value in a cell as a cell reference in a formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150861/using-the-value-in-a-cell-as-a-cell-reference-in-a-formula)

Comment: Italian version: =SOMMA(A1:INDIRETTO(CONCATENA("A";B1)))

Answer (score 6):

You can also use OFFSET:

```
OFFSET($A$10,-$B$1+1,0,$B$1)
```

It moves the range $A$10 up by $B$1-1 (becomes $A$6 ($A$5)) and then resizes the range to $B$1 rows (becomes $A$6:$A$10 ($A$5:$A$10))

Comment: Italian version: =SCARTO($A$10;-$B$1+1;0;$B$1)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option.  It works by using making an `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(...))` from the `ROW` and `COLUMN` of the start cell, `A1`, down to the initial row + the number of rows held in `B1`.

```
SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(A1),COLUMN(A1))):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(A1)+B1,COLUMN(A1))))
```

`A1`: is the start of data in a the "A" column

`B1`: is the number of rows to sum

Comment: In Italian: =SOMMA(INDIRETTO(INDIRIZZO(RIF.RIGA(A1);RIF.COLONNA(A1))):INDIRETTO(INDIRIZZO(RIF.RIGA(A1)+B1;RIF.COLONNA(A1))))

Answer (score 1):

This should be close to what you are looking for your first example:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A1:A"&B1,TRUE))
```

This should be close to what you are looking for your final example:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A"&1+B1&":A"&B1,TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on answer by @Cici I give here a more generic solution:

=SUM(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(B1,C1)):INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(B2,C2)))

In Italian version of Excel:

=SOMMA(INDIRETTO(CONCATENA(B1;C1)):INDIRETTO(CONCATENA(B2;C2)))

Where B1-C2 cells hold these values:

- A, 1
- A, 5

You can change these valuese to change the final range at wish.

---

Splitting the formula in parts:

- SUM(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(B1,C1)):INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(B2,C2)))
- CONCATENATE(B1,C1) - result is A1
- INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(B1,C1)) -   result is reference to A1

Hence:

=SUM(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(B1,C1)):INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(B2,C2)))

results in

=SUM(A1:A5)

---

I'll write down here a couple of SEO keywords for Italian users:

- come creare dinamicamente l'indirizzo di un intervallo in excel
- formula per definire un intervallo di celle in excel.

Con la formula indicata qui sopra basta scrivere nelle caselle da B1 a C2 gli estremi dell'intervallo per vedelo cambiare dentro la formula stessa.

Answer (score -1):

Old post but this is exactly what I needed, simple question, how to change it to count column rather than Row. Thankyou in advance. Novice to Excel.

```
=SUM(A1:INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A",C5)))
```

I.e My data is A1 B1 C1 D1 etc  rather then A1 A2 A3 A4.

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?