# Interpret value from formula as a formula in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have formula which I'm using to dynamically create formulas to reference data in separate spreadsheets.

For example, I have a formula in cell which returns `=<path>\[<file>]<reference>`. So the return value for cell `R496` would be the string `='D:\Documents\[Filename.xls]sheet1'!$A$3`.

[image: Example of formula]

According to [Apple Pie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12150950/3357935) on 
*[Using the value in a cell as a cell reference in a formula](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12150861/3357935)*, I can reference values from another cell in a formula my formula by using `=INDIRECT(reference)`. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work when interpreting a full formula from another cell.

[image: Attempting to use =INDIRECT()]

In [Microsoft Excel 2013 and above](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FORMULATEXT-function-0a786771-54fd-4ae2-96ee-09cda35439c8), I would be able to use `=FORMULATEXT()`, but unfortunately that option is not available in Excel 2010.

[image: =INDIRECT() not available]

**How can I use the value from a cell as a formula in Microsoft Excel 2010?**

Comment: As this is just a reference to one cell, remove the `=` in your formula, then use INDIRECT.

Comment: What is the formula to get R496

Comment: @ScottCraner It's split into multiple parts. Get [current file path](https://superuser.com/q/1226805/358766) with `=LEFT(CELL("filename",A487),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A487))-1)`. Calculate file name with `=$C496 & " " & $B496 & ".xls"`. Final formula reference in `R496` is `=("='" & $P496 & "[" & $Q496 & "]" & "sheet1'!$H$3")`

Comment: That is not what I asked.  What is the exact formula in `R496`

Comment: @ScottCraner Just edited my comment. The formula is unfortunately fairly complex

Comment: `=INDIRECT("'" & $P496 & "[" & $Q496 & "]" & "sheet1'!$H$3")` You need to remove the `=` in the string

Comment: You then can substitute each cell reference in the string with the formula found in each cell: `=INDIRECT("'" & LEFT(CELL("filename",A487),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A487))-‌​1) & "[" & $C496 & " " & $B496 & ".xls" & "]" & "sheet1'!$H$3")`

Comment: @ScottCraner Indirect is giving me "Invalid cell reference" errors, even with simple formulas like `=INDIRECT(8*8)`

Comment: `8*8` is not a cell reference `A1` is a cell reference. As I said in my first comment, Your formula is a single cell reference and therefore will work.  INDIRECT will not take a string that looks like a formula and evaluate it.  You will need VBA for that.  INDIRECT will take a string that looks like cell references and make them that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148802/discussion-between-steven-vascellaro-and-scott-craner).

Comment: The comments added unseen characters.  Try my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

To return a cell's formula rather than its value, use `FORMULATEXT()`.  So if **A1** contains:

```
=A2 + A4
```

then pick some cell and enter:

```
=FORMULATEXT(A1)
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

If you have Excel 2010, you could use the following *UDF()*:

```
Public Function MyFormula(r As Range) As String
    MyFormula = r(1).Formula
End Function
```

**EDIT#2:**

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: The `=FORMULATEXT()' function is not available in Microsoft Excel 2010. However, this formula will work in Excel 2013 or later.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: How do I add User Defined Formulas to Excel?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro  See my **EDIT#2**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & LEFT(CELL("filename",A487),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A487))-1) & "[" & $C496 & " " & $B496 & ".xls" & "]" & "sheet1'!$H$3")
```

---

As you want a more general method to evaluate a formula. You will need to use this UDF:

```
Function MyEvaluate(rng as range)
    MyEvaluate = rng.parent.Evaluate(rng.value)
End Function
```

[image]

There is still no need for the `=` at the beginning, but will not hurt either.

Comment: Can you explain how this formula is meant to work? It's not functioning properly for me

Comment: It is the concatenated version of all your cells.  it should create the string: `'D:\Documents\[Filename.xls]sheet1'!$A$3` and then return the value in that cell as INDIRECT turns strings that look like references into actual references.  For example `=INDIRECT("B" & 2)` will return the value in `B2`