# Using the value in a cell as a cell reference in a formula (extension question)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Unfortunately I do not have enough 'reputation' to post a comment on an existing post which potentially will answer my question (with some modification).

For the answer given in [Using the value in a cell as a cell reference in a formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150861/using-the-value-in-a-cell-as-a-cell-reference-in-a-formula)
how may I achieve the same behaviour for my current 'direct' formula `=INDEX(I2:I7,MODE(MATCH(I2:I7,I2:I7,0)))`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: replace each `I2:I7` with `INDIRECT(<start cell here> & ":" & <end cell here>)`

Comment: Thank you. worked perfectly. If you submit that as the answer I will accept. Kudos to you.